# German for "ditto" in 1809 record?

Tags: meaning, translation, abbreviation

In an 1809 marriage record, I see a word that logically equates to "ditto" in the date column. I have searched online translators, even considered Latin, exchanging the first letter. The word looks like Bodem, but what is the German word?

[image: handwritten excerpt]

---

Here is the preceding with a similar example.
[image: another full page]

Comment: I didn't think it was appropriate to include the entire image, but will try to attach it. It is a single word, in the date column, obviously a "ditto", because it repeats the previous entry's date. Thanks for the suggestion. I am new and learning.

Comment: The context is always important, so it is definitely appropriate to include the entire image.

Comment: By the way, the English "ditto" is the same as the German "[dito](https://www.korrekturen.de/beliebte_fehler/ditto.shtml)".

Comment: "Ditto/dito" is actually a shortened version of the expression "idem ditto/dito". "Idem" means "same", and obviously has the same root as the "eodem" identified by @fluctuatingpsychosis.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suppose this reads *[eodem](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aentry%3Deodem)*, Latin for "in the same place", and – if it doesn't refer to a place of birth, death, or marriage, but to a date – is a short form of *eodem die*, "on the same day".